# Should I sanitize a text from a contact form before sending it to my email?

Tags: node.js, express, security, sanitization

I have a contact form on a React app. When the user sends the message, it hits a `/contact` route on my node server. This route calls a `MailService`, that dispatches the text to my own gmail address.

It works, but what if someone writes shady scripts such as `<iframe onLoad="do-nasty-stuff">` instead of a regular message? Will the text be safe by nature because of email providers (it would be pure html or text after all) or should I sanitize it before sending it to me?

If I must sanitize the text, what is the best way to do it in node/express?

The code looks like this:

```js
export class MailControler {
  static contact({ email, topic, message }: ContactForm) {
    return transporter.sendMail({
      from: email,
      to: myemail,
      subject: topic,
      html: message, // TODO: SANITIZE MESSAGE ?
    });
  }
  }
```